# Vectors Intersection in 3D space

Tags: c, excel, math, arduino, algebra

I programming up an Arduino board (using C and experimenting in Excel to get my calculations right).

I need some help calculating the location of a target within a particular range in 3 dimensions.

I have a sensor system that gives the distance at each detector to a target
Four detectors are 50mm apart on the top rectangular plane A,B,C,D
The co-ordinates of the corners on the example cube are:

```
A: (-25,25,0); 
B: (25,25,0); 
C: (-25,25,0); 
D: (-25,-25,0) [Sensor plane]
E: (-25,25,-50); 
F: (25,25,-50); 
G: (-25,25,-50); 
H: (-25,-25,-50)
```

The target `T1` is resting at `(2,7,-26)`

I calculate the distance from (4 decimals)
A to `T1 = 32.4500`, B to `T1 = 29.2060`, C to `T1 = 39.4081` and D to `T1 = 41.8688`

In reality there is no cube, I only have the known distances between the sensors and the range (Distance) that the Target is from each Sensor and the Target could be anywhere within 1 meter of the Sensor but never above the Sensor plane.

Anybody out there able to let me know how I can work out Target's (x,y,z) from these fixed points and the four distances in algebra or trig.

Much appreciated as I need to keep the code tight since there's not that much room.

[image: Examples]

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trilateration

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is (currently) a maths problem (more on-topic for http://math.stackexchange.com), not a programming problem - the code should be obvious once you've nailed the maths.

Comment: Cheers Oliver, I've had a quick look, Got a headache now :-)  Struggle to understand the maths.

Comment: What type of senors do you use? Are you sure they measure distance to exactly the same point?

Comment: Yes the sensors are polar specific to north pole of a small electro-magnet.